# How to remove the __unaligned specifier from pointer types and pointer-to-pointer types

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, winapi, visual-c++

On Windows while targeting x86-64, we have the [`__unaligned`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177389.aspx) specifier.<sup>1</sup> <sup>2</sup> It's a nuisance. I want to: 1) compile-time test for it; 2) strip the specifier from a type at compile-time; and 3) cast it away when I find it in results from function calls. Casting it away happens to require [`const_cast`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/const-cast-operator), as luck would have it, so any solution probably won't easily preserve `const`-ness.

Additionally, given the pointer-driven nature of the [ITEMIDLIST](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773321(v=vs.85).aspx) types (P[C][U]IDLIST_ABSOLUTE, P[C][U]IDLIST_RELATIVE...) in the Windows Shell API, it would be nice to have the above work with pointers to pointers.

How does one achieve this?

---

Here's a handy code sample to work from:

```
int main(int, char**)
{
    //test that aligned_cast works for non-const pointers
    using AType = int __unaligned *;
    int a_data = 1;
    AType a = &a_data;
    auto aa = aligned_cast<int *>(a);

    //check that it works for const pointers
    using BType = const int __unaligned *;
    const int b_data = 2;
    BType b = &b_data;
    auto *bb = aligned_cast<const int *>(b);

    //int *bbb = aligned_cast<int *>(b); <--won't compile, good

    //check that remove_aligned really is doing its job
    using CType = remove_aligned<AType>::type;
    static_assert (is_aligned<CType>::value, "");

    //auto aaa = aligned_cast<int **>(&a); <-- &a cannot be passed as a reference

    return 0;
}
```

1) `__unaligned` is a curious quirk <strike>of the</strike> that lingers from before the Itanium era. It snuck into the Windows API, so we (on Windows) are stuck with it. We mostly don't use `ITEMIDLIST`s, and when we do, we generally `#define STRICT_TYPE_ITEMIDS` and tread carefully. The problem is that `reinterpret_cast`-ing those types is *incredibly* annoying (and then `const_cast`ing to get rid of the `__unaligned` specifier, if needed).

2) Edit: If you are unconvinced that `__unaligned` doesn't apply anymore **when targeting x86-64**, play around with my answer on Godbolt and see if it compiles without casting. Specifically, change the following lines from the test harness causes compilation failure:

```
59   //auto aa = aligned_cast<int *>(a);
60    int *aa = a; //nope, a is int __unaligned *
```

Comment: Doesn't this (from your link):  _"The __unaligned modifier is valid for the x64 and Itanium compilers but affects only applications that target an IPF computer."_ invalidate the question unless you are targeting IPF in which case you need it?

Comment: @RichardCritten No, as by your quote, it only *affects* IPF systems, i.e. Itanium, even though the modifier *exists* on x64. In fact, this is the heart of my problem.

Comment: The `__unaligned` modifier predates Itanium. It applies to all alignment-sensitive platforms, such as MIPS and PowerPC. It just so happens that at the time the documentation was written, MIPS and PowerPC were no longer relevant. Removing `__unaligned` means that your code will crash on alignment-sensitive systems. For systems that aren't alignment-sensitive, the `UNALIGNED` symbol maps to nothing, so it has already been removed for you.

Comment: @RaymondChen All respect to you Raymond, but I'm not using the `UNALIGNED` macro. And the `__unaligned` specifier participates in overload resolution, etc. Since the Windows Shell uses typedefs that include `__unaligned`, I must deal.

Comment: And since the "IL*" functions take a myriad set of aligned and unaligned typefefs of ITEMIDLIST, I need to freely cast between without concerning myself with the specifier.

Comment: @RaymondChen: I'm using MSVC 2017 targeting x86-64. I have corrected the question to reflect this. Using `__unaligned` on a 32-bit MSVC compiler doesn't work at all, which explains why everyone is so confused about why I'm asking this question.

Comment: Instead of using `__unaligned`, use `UNALIGNED`. This compiles out to nothing on systems that don't have alignment requirements (which is all the systems you care about), so the attribute should simply vanish.

Comment: @RaymondChen The attribute will not simply vanish from the Windows headers. So no, that will not work. To quote from above "Since the Windows Shell uses typedefs that include `__unaligned`, I must deal."

Comment: Hm, I thought they use the `UNALIGNED` macro but I guess not. You could always sledgehammer it: `#define __unaligned` before including the header files. I would prefer just toughing it out because that lets your code work on processors that are alignment sensitive.

Comment: @RaymondChen I hadn't thought of using `#define __unaligned`. That's clever, assuming I surround it with platform and environment checks. I probably won't use it myself, but others may find it useful. Why not post it as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution with inline explanations. There are <strike>two</strike>three caveats:

1. This isn't a built-in operator, so `int **foo = aligned_cast<int **>(&bar)` is out (the result of `&bar` is an rvalue).
2. This won't work if the pointers themselves are marked __unaligned (I'm not even sure if that's a thing, though).
3. It probably removes the cv-qualification of the pointer itself (`int __unaligned * const` becomes `int *`). I have not tested for this, as I have been working on this for over nine hours and am tired.

Anyway,

```
#include <utility>

//remove_all_pointers simply wipes out any pointers so we can get to the raw type (plus its cv-qualifiers)
template <class T>
struct remove_all_pointers { using type = T; };

template <class T>
struct remove_all_pointers<T *> { using type = remove_all_pointers<T>; };

template <class T>
using remove_all_pointers_t = typename remove_all_pointers<T>::type;

//this selector works like is_const, only it catches __unaligned instead
template<class T>
struct is_aligned_helper : std::true_type {};

template<class T>
struct is_aligned_helper<__unaligned T> : std::false_type {};

//wipe all pointers before we check for __unaligned
template<class T , class = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer_v<T>>>
struct is_aligned : is_aligned_helper<remove_all_pointers_t<T>> {};

template<class T>
using is_aligned_v = typename is_aligned<T>::value;

template <class T>
struct remove_aligned_helper { using type = T; };

template <class T>
struct remove_aligned_helper<__unaligned T> { using type = T; };

template <class T>
struct remove_aligned
{
    //remove the pointer, remove the __unaligned specifier, then put the pointer back
    using type = std::add_pointer_t<
        typename remove_aligned_helper<
            std::remove_pointer_t<T>>::type>;
};

//we can specialize for pointers to pointers, too
template <class T>
struct remove_aligned<T **> {
    using type = std::add_pointer_t<typename remove_aligned<T *>::type>;
};

template <class T>
using remove_aligned_t = typename remove_aligned<T>::type;

template <class To, class From, class = std::enable_if<std::is_pointer<From>() && !is_aligned<From>()>>
constexpr To aligned_cast(From &value) noexcept
{
    return reinterpret_cast<To>(const_cast<remove_aligned_t<From>>(value));
}

int main(int, char**)
{
    //check that it works at all
    using AType = int __unaligned *;
    int a_data = 1;
    AType a = &a_data;
    int * aa = aligned_cast<int *>(a);
    (void)aa;
    //check that it works for const pointers
    using BType = const int __unaligned *;
    const int b_data = 2;
    BType b = &b_data;
    const int *bb = aligned_cast<const int *>(b);
    (void)bb;
    //int *bbb = aligned_cast<int *>(b); //<--won't compile, good

    //check that remove_aligned really is doing its job
    using CType = remove_aligned<AType>::type;
    static_assert (is_aligned<CType>::value, "");

    //check that T** works
    AType *d = &a;
    int ** aaa = aligned_cast<int **>(d); //<-- &a cannot be passed as a reference
    (void)aaa;
}
```

Here's [the code](https://godbolt.org/g/Vv9Kcx) on Godbolt.